# What is the C# equivalent of PowerShell's Get-CimSession?

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi

I would like to reuse CIM sessions for WMI queries.  PowerShell has Get-CimSession which can enumerate active CIM sessions for reuse.  The only thing I was able to do in C# is query the last known CIM session's computer attribute:

```
CimSession cimSession1;
cimSession1 = CimSession.Create(computer1);
string str = cimSession1.ComputerName;
```

and create a new CIM session if needed.

Comment: The powershell Cim cmdlets use session state storage, it's not like they persist after you close the host application.

Comment: Just save the CimSession into a variable.